# How to show the layout one above another look like layer?

Tags: android

I want to show more activities or dialogs one above another look like layer below,Is there any library for that?[image]

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/txusballesteros/sliding-deck  , try this it might help

Comment: You can do it, but just open new AlertDialog on Click of perticuler buttons.

Comment: yes, but it hides parent layout.

Comment: Use transperent Backgroud in you parent Layout. or You can apply Dialog theme to your alert dialog.

Comment: Thanks,i will try and let you know

Comment: Layering (Stacking) of Views will be done automatically if you open multiple dialogs. And you cannot do layering of activities, for that, you have to go with Fragments.

Comment: It's showing one above another in transparent activity itself

Comment: you can give dialog theme to your activity

Comment: <activity android:name=".FirstActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">

Comment: <style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

Comment: assign this "DialogTheme" theme to your activity

Comment: Had you get what you want?

Comment: No,still it hide the parent dialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103294/discussion-between-bhoomika-and-yazhini).