# why android:layout_above="@id/mh01" is wrong when i use RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

in my layout why 
android:layout_above="@id/mh01" is wrong when i use RelativeLayout !

[image]

[image]

I don't know why this is wrong

**Update :**

I have deal with the problem that the description of title. but I meet a new problem
This XML code have something wrong:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mh011"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mh01"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mh022"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mh02"
                android:layout_above="@+id/mh011"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/mh033"
                android:background="@drawable/mh_03"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mh011"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/mh044"
                android:background="@drawable/mh04"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mh011"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/mh055"
                android:background="@drawable/mh05"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mh011"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

> 
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is quote on top left remove that

Comment: remove double quote from first line and  also add plus symbol while referring id  @+id/mh01

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're strongly discouraged to post your code as screenshots.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are referring to

Comment: @Yazhini **NO**. The `+` sign is only required for **anticipated referencing**, which I personally don't recommend.

Comment: @Hrundi is it good practice without using + symbol while refering elements id?

Comment: @Yazhini Yes. But obviously, the referred View must be created **before** the one which refers it. Let's say it's a bit of "reverse thinking" the UI. First you anchor the "fixed" Views and then add the Views which relate to them.

Comment: @Hrundi you have any idea about how to do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361259/how-to-show-the-layout-one-above-another-look-like-layer

Comment: @Yazhini It seems a custom ListView inside a custom dialog.

Comment: Your new xml error is an extra **>** before `</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Try set:

```
android:contentDescription="@null"
```

in all imageView

**your  code after edit :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mh011"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mh01"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mh022"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mh02"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mh011"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/mh033"
            android:background="@drawable/mh_03"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mh011"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:contentDescription="@null"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/mh044"
            android:background="@drawable/mh04"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mh011"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/mh055"
            android:background="@drawable/mh05"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mh011"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:contentDescription="@null" 
               />

          > 
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I try but it's no effect

Comment: I change the id of imageView  that it's effictive but I meet a new problem.

Comment: @sitinglin update Your question and set your XML code and i will check it

Comment: It's my first time use SO. I try.

Comment: never mind , Press in text edit in your question and set your XML code  and save it

Comment: It's not very easy for me .I spend long time to send my code.

Comment: am not found any error in your **XML** ! , what your wrong msg now !?

Comment: the IDE prompt that missing content description attribute on image  on imageView

Comment: It's no effect ,IDE prompt that Cannot resolve symbol '@string/description

Comment: try `android:contentDescription="@null"`

Comment: You are right! But there are a new problem: with  the code "android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mh011" the IDE prompt that consider adding android:layout_toStartOf ="@+id/mh011" to better suppoet right-to-left layouts " What's mean?

Comment: show this answer will help you in your new problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25301078/4967569

Comment: Your answer is useful to me ! The  tick icon turn green that is means i accept your answer?